# How can I access my android smartphone's both front and rear camera through a web app?

Tags: javascript, android, camera

I want to access my android smartphones both front and rear camera through a web app. I came across a web app in Jsfiddle which I modified according to my need and was trying on my android phone to access my android front and rear camera but was unable to do.

Please visit this web app at : https://jsfiddle.net/cf90az9q/19/

I am viewing this app from chrome browser version:53 on my android smartphone. 
Here the button Switch Camera is intended to change from front camera to rear and vice versa on every click.

If I attach 2 webcams to my desktop and try to access the cameras , I am able to do so without any problem.

But when I try on my mobile by visiting the above web address, I am able to access my mobiles rear camera but when I click again to access my front camera, a black screen is displayed and hence I am unable to access. Can someone please tell me how can I access both my android cameras.

A small note : Following line of code at line no.141 in javascript section toggles between 0 and 1 for every click and here '0' refers to front camera and '1' refers to rear camera.

```
        v = (v?0:1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access both cameras simultaneously on most Android devices. The only ones i know of that let you access both at the same time are the HTC m8, the OnePlusOne and the Motorola Nexus 6.